# Android Studio: Setup external project as module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I need to use an external project(ResuableProject) as module in multiple projects(one of which is ProjectOne). What I've done here so far is:

Added following in settings.gradle of ProjectOne

```
include ':ProjectOne', ':ResuableProject'
project(':ResuableProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../ResuableProject/module')
```

Added following in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ResuableProject')
}
```

After that gradle sync without any error and in Project Explorer the module is included but when I use any class from `ResuableProject` it gives me an error that class cannot be found until I click on class name and it give me an option to `add dependency on ResuableProject`. When I select the option the class is accessible and it seems all working fine.
But when I Build the project and try to run it gives me this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':ProjectOne:compileDevDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(10, 30) error: package <packagename of ResuableProject> does not exist
```

Am I missing something or do I have to include source directory of ResuableProject in ProjectOne, if yes the how?

Also is there a better way to use one common project across multiple apps? (not jar or maven cause I need to include source with every project and common project will be hosted in a separate git repo)

Previously I was using this approach with Eclipse (one common Library project) and including it in multiple apps.

UPDATE: Adding file system structure

```
workspace
----ResuableProject (Android Common stuff)
--------.git
--------module
----ProjectOne (Android App One)
--------.git
--------ProjectOne (module)
------------build.gradle
--------settings.gradle
----ProjectOne (Android App Two)
--------.git
--------ProjectOne (module)
```

Comment: Where are ResuableProject and ProjectOne in files system? Could you show approximate location of folders?

Comment: Just added in the question.

Comment: Does ResuableProject have build.gradle file with appropriate settings your ResuableProject?

Comment: Where is the settings.gradle located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that you can add `ResuableProject` but cannot use its source if build.gradle has value `apply plugin: 'android'` i.e. the type of the project is application.

I changed that to `apply plugin: 'android-library'` i.e. it must be a library and now everything is working fine.

Comment: I keep having trouble with this that the external libraries required by the "reusable object" don't get loaded and the build fails because of that. Do I need any more settings somewhere?